# Dispatch custom event with namespace

Tags: events, event-handling, d3.js

I'm trying to use the 'd3.dispatch' feature in one of my project. I want to setup 
a custom event and dispatch it to the available listenres using namespace.

I did this :

```
var dispatcher = d3.dispatch("period_selected");

brush.on("brush", function() {
  var s =  brush.extent()

  // patch the event to listeners
  dispatcher.period_selected(s);

});

// register listener for the event namespaced 
dispatcher.on("period_selected.my_namespace", function(s,f) {

    console.log(event.period_selected);
});
```

But I can't get back the  with namespace as result. Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The namespace is not passed as an argument, nor assigned to the event. If you'd *really* like the namespace, then you should pass that along as a parameter:

`dispatch.period_selected(s, "my_namespace")`

...which then would be available here:

```
dispatcher.on("period_selected.namespace", function(s, namespace) {
    // Use namespace here
});
```